# Formula for $\sum2^{k^2}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

Is there a formula for the sum $s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k^2}$? I know that $\sum^n2^k=2(2^n-1)$ but I dont know if I can use that.
If not, is there a big-O upper bound?

Comment: The sequence $2,18,530,66066$ is not even in OEIS. I think that the simplest way to compute $s(n)$ is the obvious one.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1}-1$ is quite obvious when you write it in base $2$, and there is no such formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k^2}$

Comment: @ajotatxe and what would be the obvious one? Something like Euler-Mclaurin or really just adding up?

Comment: An upper bound would be the last term, $O(2^{n^2})$.

Comment: S(n) is almost $2^{n^2}$.